# requires clause for a non-template member function in a template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++20, requires-clause

I have a simple template class `A`. I want to enable a function if some requirements are satisfied.

### Solution 1 - `requires` clause

The first solution I tried is the following:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    void a(void) requires (same_as<T, int>)
    {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

This works pretty well. I can call `A<int>().a()` but not `A<char>().a();`. Also, IntelliSense correctly identifies usage errors in Visual Studio.

I tried to move the function definition outside the class but I got C2511 compiler error in Visual Studio. In GCC, it works fine.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    void a(void) requires (same_as<T, int>);
};

template <class T>
void A<T>::a(void)
requires (same_as<T, int>)
{
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}
```

Do you think my code is incorrect or is it a visual studio compiler bug/incomplete feature?

---

### Solution 2 - `static_assert`

This solution works in some cases, but of course it would cause compile errors if you try an explicit  template instantiation (for example `template class A<char>`). Also, IntelliSense would not correctly identify improper usages.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:

    void a(void);
};

template <class T>
void A<T>::a(void)
{
    static_assert(same_as<T, int>);
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}
```

---

### Soluton 3 - `enable_if`

#### (wrong)

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:

    template <std::enable_if_t<same_as<T, int>, bool> = true>
    void a(void);
};

template <class T>
template <std::enable_if_t<same_as<T, int>, bool>>
void A<T>::a(void)
{
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}
```

This solution has the same problems as #2. Moreover, I would prefer not to add some templates that are not understandable at first sight.

---

### Solution 4 - some weird compile time inheritance

```
template <class T>
class A_base { /*common stuff*/ };

template <class T>
class A : public A_base<T>
{
public:
    A_base<T>::A_base;

    /* non-int stuff*/
};

template <>
class A<int> : public A_base<int>
{
public:
    A_base<int>::A_base;

    void a(void) {};
};
```

This would work well, but it could get quite complex in some situations, and very unpleasant for debugging when a bunch of levels are nested.

---

Do you have any advice / better solution?

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit:

- solution #3 does not work, I made a mistake;
- I am using msvc 16.7.0, Build Tools x64/x86 (v14.27)

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the ancient `a(void)` baggage, as inherited from C, and declare the class method as, simply, `a()`?

Comment: Your use of `enable_if` is wrong. There is no SFINAE there. Which is why it fails you.

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce your issue in msvc (https://godbolt.org/z/xEEGv9). Seems you use a release with a bug in concept support.

Comment: - @SamVarshavchik nothing changed after removing `void`  
- @StoryTeller is right, the `enable_if` solution does not work  
- @StoryTeller [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7oqKaE) reproduces my issue, owever it works fine in gcc. I think this is a msvc bug

Answer (score 4):

> Do you think my code is incorrect or is it a visual studio compiler bug/incomplete feature?

The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/cWvrKscx5) is **well-formed** and as of 2022 is accepted by the latest version of all the three major compilers. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cWvrKscx5). The member function `a` is a **templated entity** as per [temp.pre#8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#8.3) and `C++20` allows the use of `requires-clause` with a templated entity as per [dcl.decl#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#4) which states:

> **The optional requires-clause in an `init-declarator` or `member-declarator` shall be present only if the declarator declares a templated function** ([dcl.fct]). When present after a declarator, the requires-clause is called the trailing requires-clause.
> The trailing requires-clause introduces the constraint-expression that results from interpreting its constraint-logical-or-expression as a constraint-expression.

(emphasis mine)

This means that the code given in solution 1 of your question is valid. For reference I am also posting the code below:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    void a(void) requires (same_as<T, int>);
};
//well-formed as per C++20
template <class T>
void A<T>::a(void)
requires (same_as<T, int>)
{
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSVC C++ Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) states that [P0734R0 Concepts](https://wg21.link/P0734R0) is available from VS 2019 16.3.

Could you possibly be using VS 2017 which does not have the same support for C++20 with MSVC?

Comment: I'm using VS2019 16.7.0